# Is there a way to set metadata to a set of VMs?

Tags: google-compute-engine

Is there a way to apply metadata to a group of VM instances? Also is there a group of all metadata key/value pairs that are supported/predefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your use case by [adding project-level key value pairs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#projectwide) either using the console, gcloud command or API. This way key value pair is applied to all the instances. Here is the information to set of [default metadata entries](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#default) using which you can query your instance or project information. You can view some examples in this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41597059/whats-the-best-way-to-add-project-level-metadata-to-a-google-cloud-project) thread.